# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 145.6 Mb using RMarkdown

Tags: r, memory-management, odbc, r-markdown, tidyverse

Have been wracking my brain on what to do about this but basically I have written code on a sample set of my data (300k rows) in RMarkdown. Works perfectly. Now I wish to add the following but then I get the error seen above.

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "DSN", uid="id.com")
customers <- DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn,"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE")
gc()
```

`MYTABLE` is 7 million rows long and my code breaks at this chunk:

```
customers %>%
  select(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,
         ID
         ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Marketing Variables", values_to = "count") %>%
  filter(is.na(count) == FALSE) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = `Marketing Variables`, fill = count), position = "fill")
```

But even if i take this out, its just the next chunk that will break. and then that chunk will break. etc etc.

So How can I knit my rmd when connecting to a database and have it output the html I desire..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let SQL do the heavy lifting using `dbplyr`. So start by connecting to a database and creating a dbplyr specific tibble:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "DSN", uid="id.com")
customers <- tbl(myconn, "MYTABLE")
```

When you run your commands on this object, the equivalent functions from `dbplyr`, which have the same names, are used automatically:

```
plot_data <- customers %>%
  select(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,
         ID
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Marketing Variables", values_to = "count") %>%
  filter(is.na(count) == FALSE) %>% 
  count(`Marketing Variables`)
```

Note, that I moved the counting up here, so it's done by `dbplyr` instead of `ggplot2`. Yet, behind the scenes, this is only writing the query. You can display the SQL code with:

```
plot_data %>% 
  show_query()
```

Nothing has been loaded to your environment so far. But if you are ready to use the reduced dataset in R, your can  `collect()` it:

```
plot_data %>% 
  collect() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = `Marketing Variables`, y = n, fill = count), position = "fill")
```

Obviously, I wasn't able to test this since I don't have access to your database. But I hope it points you in the right general direction. There is also a helpful guide I can recommend: https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: So it is a snowflake connection FYI, but I am unable to run tbl() in the way u rcommended. customers_test <- tbl(myconn, "db.schema.mytable")

Comment: The documentation for that command can be found [here](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl.src_dbi.html). Maybe you can try `tbl(myconn, from = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE")`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your memory limit first by running

```
memory.limit()
```

then allocate the memory memory

```
memory.limit(9999999999)
```

Close all your other programmes opened + run `gc()` in your console before you start the analysis.